# How to change the icon-image on click

Tags: polygon, javascript, markers, mapbox-gl-js

I am using Mapbox and I am trying to change the icon-image by clicking on it, for example I want to change this:

[image: normal icon image]

With this when I click:

[image: icon image when clicked]

```
map.on('load', function() {
    map.loadImage('./images/marker-removebg-preview.png',
    function(error, image) {
            if (error) throw error;
            map.addImage('marker', image);
        }
    );
});

var draw = new MapboxDraw({
    displayControlsDefault: false,
    controls: {
        polygon:true,
        trash: true,
    },
    userProperties: true,
      styles: [
          {
          "id": "gl-draw-polygon-stroke-active",//change le style des lignes de polygon
          "type": "line",
          "layout": {
            "line-cap": "round",
            "line-join": "round"
          },
          "paint": {
            "line-color": "#D20C0C",
            "line-dasharray": [0.2, 2],
            "line-width": 2
          }
        },

        {
          "id": "gl-draw-polygon-and-line-vertex-active",//change le style des points de polygon
          "type": "symbol",
          "filter": ["all", ["==", "meta", "vertex"], ["==", "$type", "Point"], ["!=", "mode", "static"]],
          "layout": {
            "icon-image": "marker",
            'icon-size': 0.06
            }   
         }

       ]

    });var draw = new MapboxDraw({
    displayControlsDefault: false,
    controls: {
        polygon:true,
        trash: true,
    },
    userProperties: true,
      styles: [
          {
          "id": "gl-draw-polygon-stroke-active",//change le style des lignes de polygon
          "type": "line",
          "layout": {
            "line-cap": "round",
            "line-join": "round"
          },
          "paint": {
            "line-color": "#D20C0C",
            "line-dasharray": [0.2, 2],
            "line-width": 2
          }
        },

    {
      "id": "gl-draw-polygon-and-line-vertex-active",//change le style des points de polygon
      "type": "symbol",
      "filter": ["all", ["==", "meta", "vertex"], ["==", "$type", "Point"], ["!=", "mode", "static"]],
      "layout": {
        "icon-image": "marker",
        'icon-size': 0.06
        }   
     }

   ]

});
```

I tried this method but it didn't work

```
map.on('click', 'gl-draw-polygon-and-line-vertex-active', function (e) {
    // load a smaller cat image
    map.loadImage('./images/marqueur_avec_camera.png', function(error, image) {
        if (error) throw error;
    map.addImage('marker-img', image);
    // change the icon-image property of the points layer to the smaller cat
    map.setLayoutProperty('gl-draw-polygon-and-line-vertex-active', 'icon-image', 'marker-img'); 

  });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a good question.

Typically you'd use [`feature-state`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#setfeaturestate) for this like in https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/hover-styles/, however `feature-state` doesn't support the `icon-image` layout property yet.

You can use `setLayoutProperty` but you'll need a unique id in the source so that you can use this when evaluating the icon-image, eg. using a match expression checking against the ['id'] similar to https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/data-driven-circle-colors/. So for example

```js
map.on('click', 'layer-name', e => {
  map.setLayoutProperty('layer-name', 'icon-image',
    [
      'match',
      ['id'], // get the feature id (make sure your data has an id set or use generateIds for GeoJSON sources
      e.features[0].id, 'image-selected', //image when id is the clicked feature id
      'image-default' // default
    ]
  )
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so if i understand correctly i have to match the id like this `map.setLayoutProperty(['match',['get', 'gl-draw-polygon-and-line-vertex-active'],'marker-img']);`

Comment: Probably `map.setLayoutProperty('gl-draw-polygon-and-line-vertex-active', 'icon-image', ['match', ['id'], e.features[0].id, 'image-selected', 'image-default'])` see https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#match and https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#setlayoutproperty

Comment: i tried it too but it doesn't work `map.on('click', 'gl-draw-polygon-and-line-vertex-active', e => {
  map.setLayoutProperty('gl-draw-polygon-and-line-vertex-active', 'icon-image',
    [
      'match',
      ['id'], 
      e.features[1].id, 'marker-img', 
      'marker' // default
    ]
  )
})`