# How to change the icon image when clicking off the symbol layer

Tags: javascript, mapbox, markers, mapbox-gl-js

In Mapbox, I can successfully swap marker images when clicking on a marker. However, I can't get it to change back when clicking an empty space on the map. This causes the pop-up to close, but the marker to remain in the active state.

I used the advice from the following question to change the image on click.

[How to change the icon-image on click](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/363262/how-to-change-the-icon-image-on-click)

My code:

```
map.on('click', 'points', (e) => {

    const coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
    const markup = e.features[0].properties.markup;

    while (Math.abs(e.lngLat.lng - coordinates[0]) > 180) {
        coordinates[0] += e.lngLat.lng > coordinates[0] ? 360 : -360;
    }

    new mapboxgl.Popup()
        .setLngLat(coordinates)
        .setHTML(markup)
        .addTo(map);

    // change the image from markerImage to markerImageActive on click

    map.setLayoutProperty('points', 'icon-image',
        [
            'match',
            ['id'],
            e.features[0].id, 'markerImageActive',
            'markerImage'
        ]
    )

});
```

It successfully changes back when I click on a different marker, but not an empty space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved this with an answer from a different question

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54413030/1737337

```
map.on('click', 'points', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // put this inside my existing code for clicks on the "points" layer
    // [...]
});

map.on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.defaultPrevented === false) {
        map.setLayoutProperty('points', 'icon-image', 'markerImage'); // reset all markers default hasn't been prevented (meaning I haven't clicked the points layer)
    }
});
```

Credit to [stdob--](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4989460/stdob) for this!